# Linux Network UPS Tools Setup

Tags: software-rec, ups, nut

Power failures have been wrecking my server, so I recently plugged it into a USB UPS (MEISSNER XT1200 (1200VA) UPS).

The problem is that the power failures last longer than the UPS battery can handle so I need the server to shutdown when the UPS battery is low.

I have been looking into the Network UPS Tools software and it seems to be exactly what I need although I find the documentation to be very unhelpful and difficult to follow.

Has anyone had success in installing it and if so; what are the most important steps to ensure a basic shutdown command on low UPS power?

Comment: Most important is to choose an UPS that's supported linux / unix software; most are not in my experience. I always use APC, those *do* work, at least with `apcupsd`. You don't say what brand/type UPS you have...

Comment: This is a MEISSNER XT1200 (1200VA) UPS, I don't know too much about it

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1173917 mentions that UPS and `nut` together, perhaps you can get some hints from that message...